# Why doesn't detailed balance always imply a uniform distribution for Markov Chains?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-matrices

Consider a state (row) vector $\{\pi_i\}$ and a right-stochastic matrix $P_{ij}$. To calculate the next state vector $\pi'$ you can right-multiply by $P$:
$$\pi'_i=\sum_j \pi_jP_{ji}$$
Detailed balance states that in equilibrium
$$\pi_iP_{ij}=\pi_jP_{ji}.$$
If you sum over both sides you get the following
\begin{align}
\sum_i\pi_iP_{ij}&=\sum_j\pi_jP_{ji}\\
\pi'_j&=\pi'_i
\end{align}
which seems to imply that for any $P_{ij}$ obeying the detailed balance equation, the stationary distribution is the uniform distribution since every entry of $\pi'$ is the same. However in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance#Reversible_Markov_chains) it is mentioned that only when $P$ is symmetric do we always get a uniform distribution. How can this be? I also don't fully understand the detailed balance so this might add to the confusion

Comment: You are summing on $i$ on the left-hand side and on $j$ on the right-hand side. This does not seem legitimate (unless of course if $P_{i,j}=P_{j,i}$, in which case $P$ is symmetric).

Comment: @nejimban Doesn't the detailed balance have to hold for all $i,j$? If not this might be where my confusion comes from. If it holds for all $i,j$ my reasoning was that you could keep adding pairs of detailed balance equations until you sum over all $i,j$. Ill edit my answer to explain this step some more.

Comment: @nejimban I just understood where I went wrong, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to @nejimban:
In the step where I introduced the sums I had the following idea in mind, starting from a detailed balance equation for a particular index just keep adding terms from different indices until you have a full sum. Writing this down explicitly made me realize this is not possible. I might have used Einstein-summation too much
\begin{align}
\pi_1P_{13}&=\pi_3P_{31}\\
\pi_1P_{13}+\color{blue}{\pi_2P_{23}}&=\pi_3P_{31}+\color{blue}{\pi_2P_{23}}\\
\pi_1P_{13}+\pi_2P_{23}+\color{blue}{\pi_3P_{33}}&=\pi_3P_{31}+\pi_2P_{23}+\color{blue}{\pi_3P_{33}}\\
\pi'_3&=\pi_3P_{31}+\pi_2P_{23}+\color{}{\pi_3P_{33}}\\
\pi'_3&\neq\pi'_1
\end{align}